# How to non-interactively quit RStudio gracefully

Tags: r

I am looking to make RStudio quit gracefully whilst in non- interactive mode. I have tried:

```
stop("",call = quit(save = "no",status = 0, runLast = FALSE))
```

It works when calling `RScript myscript.R` from cmd/shell.

However, when I source the file in RStudio, I get a R session aborted error. Is there anyway to do this from RStudio?

Comment: Are you getting the error from within RStudio or when you run a script from console? I find using `q()` tends to work from the latter.

Comment: Yes, I was getting this error in Rstudio. I wonder if this was cause the program was shutting down Rstudio and R studio didn't realise what was going on..

Comment: Makes sense - I edited the question a bit to more clearly outline the issue as an RStudio one, vs a non-interactive one. If its just non-interactive (i.e. calling a script from console), the code that you provided does work. If I misunderstood feel free to roll back!

Comment: Can you motivate why you are trying to do that in RStudio vs. running Rscript from the command line, and why the application must shut down automatically?

Comment: Although not graceful, how about a system / kilall call.: linux `system('killall rstudio')`: [Windows](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-kill-all-processes-with-the-same-name-in-Windows) `shell('taskkill /F /IM "rstudio.exe" /T ')`

Comment: @PhilippeMarchand It was as part of the test process, when you write the script in rstudio, you'd like to be able to test it then and there.

Answer (score 7):

The RStudio application and the R session are different processes (e.g. in Windows, if you open the Task Manager, you can see "RStudio R session" in the list of background processes). When you call `q()` interactively, it closes both, but when you source the script it only closes the R session, not the RStudio program, which then returns the error message and offers to create a new session.

There doesn't seem to be a way to close RStudio non-interactively. If there were, it would probably be in the rstudioapi package (https://github.com/rstudio/rstudioapi).