# Use quit() in RStudio without prompt about saving changes to code

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to use `quit()` in RStudio, however specifying the value of `save` only allows me to tell R about what I want to do about saving/not saving the workspace, and getting rid of that prompt.
Is there a way, be it with `quit()` or any other function, that I can get rid of the prompt which asks me if I want to save changes to the code (if changes have been made)?
May sound trivial but I have not been able to find an answer on my own.

Comment: Tools --> Global Options: Under "Workspace" set "Save workspace to .RData on exit:" to never. IMHO, that really should be the default.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for taking the time to reply, however what I was asking was different and not about the workspace: if you modify the code without saving changes, running `quit()` will generate a prompt about saving/not saving these unsaved changes to the file, regardless of the workspace stuff. Do you know if there is a way to solve that, in the same way that specifying `save` would solve the workspace prompt in `quit()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to non-interactively quit RStudio gracefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38181415/how-to-non-interactively-quit-rstudio-gracefully)

Comment: Ah, OK. No, I don't think that's possible. Why are you running R through an IDE if you want to quit programmatically?

Comment: I got curious about this and tried to replicate it on my Win10 box. When I make a new script, edit it, and don't save: (1) Closing R with the X in the upper right prompts me to save the file or not (as you describe). (2) Closing R with `q()`, including `q(save = "no")` does *not* prompt me to save the script -- *but restores it* upon relaunching RStudio, even if the file has never been saved! I also verified that "Restore previously open source documents at startup" is *unchecked* for me, as desired, and it behaves correctly when using the X to close. I don't know what to make of any of this.

Comment: I should be clearer about what I'm saying: I saw some behavior I can't explain, but I can't reproduce the behavior you described.